# i have added function name 'test' to following but error comes saying it not recognize as function.Can anyone help me

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Error**

```
Uncaught 'TypeError': ".goal_test".click is not a function
```

Code is Share in here
https://codeshare.io/aJAoeR

code which i have added is in between asterisk marks

Comment: Add a `$` before it

Comment: Try $('.goal_test').on('click', function(){})

Comment: Fixed some texts

Answer (score 1):

I just made some edit to your code and everything seems to work. Do this match what you intend to achieve?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

  $scope.goal_title = "Investing in real estate";

  $scope.dates = [
    2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2026
  ];

  $scope.goal_real_estate = false;

  for (x in $scope.dates) {
    if ($scope.dates[x] == 2016) {
      $scope.goal_real_estate_2016 = true;
    } else if ($scope.dates[x] == 2021) {
      $scope.goal_retirement_2021 = true;
    } else if ($scope.dates[x] == 2018) {
      $scope.goal_involve_2018 = true;
    } else if ($scope.dates[x] == 2026) {
      $scope.goal_test_2026 = true;
    }
  }

});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var viewport = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  console.log(viewport);


  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  })

  $('.goal_wrap').click(function() {
    var diff = $(this).parent()[0].offsetLeft;
    $('.date .goal_wrap').removeClass('active bounce');
    $(this).addClass('active bounce');
    console.log(diff);
    console.log((viewport - diff));
    TweenLite.to($('.date').parent(), 1, {
      x: ((viewport * 0.5) - diff),
      onComplete: function() {
        console.log('success');
        /*TweenLite.to($('.timeline'), 1, {top:"50%"});*/
      }
    });
  });

  $('.goal_real_estate').click(function() {
    console.log('goal click');
    $('body').fadeTo('ease', 0.3, function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://extrawall.net/images/wallpapers/378_1920x1080_abstract_city.jpg)');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

  });

  $('.goal_retirement').click(function() {
    console.log('goal click');
    $('body').fadeTo('ease', 0.3, function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/tropics_sea_palm_trees_vacation_84858_2412x1810.jpg)');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

  });

  $('.goal_involve').click(function() {
    console.log('goal click');
    $('body').fadeTo('ease', 0.3, function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.churchmilitant.com/images/uploads/2015-06-12-niles-x.jpg)');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

  });

  // test
  $('.goal_test').click(function() {
    console.log('goal click');
    $('body').fadeTo('ease', 0.3, function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://extrawall.net/images/wallpapers/378_1920x1080_abstract_city.jpg))');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

  });

  // end of test
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

body {
  background: url('http://extrawall.net/images/wallpapers/378_1920x1080_abstract_city.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.timeline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 100;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.date {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  /*padding-left: 80px;*/
}

.date::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  /*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  /*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  /*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  /*Standard*/
  margin-top: -100vh;
}

p.focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

p.focus::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 3.5px;
}

p.focus::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -5px;
  left: 9px;
}

.goal_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
  top: -100px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.goal_wrap:hover {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.goal_wrap.active {
  top: -160px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bounce {
  animation: bounce 1s .5s;
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.85);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    opacity: .7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.6)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Timeline Sequence V1</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="structure" ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeController">

    <div class="preloaderimg">
      <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/tropics_sea_palm_trees_vacation_84858_2412x1810.jpg" alt="" style="display: none;" />
      <img src="http://extrawall.net/images/wallpapers/378_1920x1080_abstract_city.jpg" alt="" style="display: none;" />
      <img src="http://www.churchmilitant.com/images/uploads/2015-06-12-niles-x.jpg" alt="" style="display: none;" />
    </div>

    <div class="timeline"></div>

    <div class="timeline">
      <div ng-repeat="date in dates track by $index" class="date date-{{$index}}">
        <div class="goal_wrap goal_real_estate" ng-show="goal_real_estate_{{date}}">
          <i class="fa fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="goal_wrap goal_involve" ng-show="goal_involve_{{date}}">
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="goal_wrap goal_retirement" ng-show="goal_retirement_{{date}}">
          <i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        ***********************************
        <!-- test -->
        <div class="goal_wrap goal_test" ng-show="goal_test_{{date}}">
          <i class="fab fa-accusoft" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        ************************************

        <!--end test -->
        <p class="focus">
          <a href="#">{{date}}</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <h1>{{goal_title}}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea to how to make this responsive.I tried but wired.appreciate your help

Comment: you can try setting the width of the timeline as `.timeline{width:max-content;}`